# How to add existing records to has_many without it saving to the DB immediately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I've got this:

```
class Pirate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parrots
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Parrot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pirate
end
```

And I've got existing Pirates and Parrots with ids 1 to 10. Now I'd like to do this:

```
p = Pirate.first
p.name = nil
p.parrot_ids = [1,2,3]
p.save if p.valid?
```

Because the pirate object is not valid (it's missing a name) I don't want it to be saved. However, the parrots are linked to the pirate now, and it's committed in the database.

How can I assign the parrots, but have the links to the parrots only saved to the database when p.save is successful? I.e., how can I save the pirate and the links to the parrots in one transaction?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably take a look at the Active Record transactions.
You can wrap your code as you have it in a transaction block. Transactions are protective blocks where SQL statements are only permanent if they can all succeed as one atomic action

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

You could rearrange your operations a bit:

```
p = Pirate.first
p.name = nil
if p.save
  p.parrot_ids = [1,2,3]
end
```

Note there's no need for "if p.valid?" after p.save; because valid? is invoked by save, determining whether an attempt is made to write the data to the database.

If your parrots were not pre-existing, you could use p.parrots.build(attributes={...}) to create new parrots that won't be saved until the pirate parent is saved.

See the section on Unsaved Objects and Associations in the [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Hi Ken, I want the parrots to participate in the validation. I have mass assignment on :parrot_ids. If validation fails because the user tried to hack in a parrot they are not allowed to link to, then p.save should fail, after which p.parrots should return the parrots the user tried.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Rails is very much built this way for existing objects; if the object already exists and you futz with its associations, an update is always triggered. If you have the ability to use the `.build` option as KenB mentioned, then that is one way to get around the issue. However, barring that, I can only think of one way to handle this at the moment; wrap the entire operation in a transaction, like so:

```
Pirate.transaction do
    p = Pirate.first
    p.name = nil
    p.parrot_ids = [1,2,3]

    if !p.save # Performing save in this manner will return false if validations fail (ie same as your p.valid?)
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback # should rollback anything executing within this transaction block
    end
end
```

Let me know if this helps, and apologies if it doesn't.

Comment: For some reason I only just noticed this question is over two years old. Sorry for the question necromancy (assuming it is no longer relevant).